# Keyboard pushs the UI out of screen in Android compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a LazyColumn with a TextField below it. When the keyboard appears, the top part of the LazyColumn will be pushed up out of the screen and I can not even scroll it down. Basically, I can not see the top part of the LazyColumn when the keyboard appears.

My code is quite simple:

```
Column {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(9f)) {
        items(3) {
            Text(text = "Item $it")
        }
    }
    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        value = "",
        onValueChange = {})
}
```

[image: UI without keyboard]

[image: UI with keyboard]

I tried each option of the `windowSoftInputMode` in Manifest, but nothing works.
I'm using `'androidx.compose.material3:material3'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that the keyboard is causing the layout to be resized and the top part of the LazyColumn is being pushed off the screen, making it impossible to scroll back up. To fix this, you can add the android:windowSoftInputMode attribute to the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file, and set it to adjustResize. This will cause the layout to be resized when the keyboard appears, ensuring that the entire LazyColumn is still visible and scrollable.

Here's an example of how you can add this attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: tried this before, nothing happened

Comment: sh*t, I invalidates the android studio and restart it, then it works. So many issues after i update to the Flamingo

Answer (score 0):

I invalidates the android studio and restart it, then it works. So many issues after i update to the Flamingo